# rails method from multiple methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, presenter, draper

So I have this code in my Rails presenter(similar to Draper gem):

```
  def title
    h.link_to 'Favor', favor_path(@favor) + asked_or_published? + user_link
  end

  def asked_or_published?
    if asked_favor?
      h.content_tag(:p, "published by")
    elsif published_favor?
      h.content_tag(:p, "asked by")
    end 
  end

  def user_link
    h.link_to @favor.favor_asker.firstname, h.user_path(@favor.favor_asker)
  end
```

And I'm calling the `title` method in my view. The problem is that calling this method only returns the `link_to 'Favor'` part and not the rest. Why is that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a grouping priority issue, the `+ asked_or_published? + user_link` bits are being added to the path generated by `favor_path(@favor)`. Not sure if they're also being escaped correctly, but that is not relevant.

Replace this:

```
h.link_to 'Favor', favor_path(@favor) + asked_or_published? + user_link
```

with:

```
h.link_to('Favor', favor_path(@favor)) + asked_or_published? + user_link
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Now I'm calling 
`def rewards
    @favor.rewards.each do |reward|
      reward.title
    end 
  end` in my view but instead of the title attribute I'm getting the whole object printed out. Could you help me with this as well? :)

Comment: Sorry, that code looks multi-line but it's rendered inline because it's a comment (stackoverflow does not support code blocks in comments). I'm not sure I understand how you're using it in the view. It does sound like a different issue, though, and it would be better to open a new question. SO is more like an encyclopaedia than a forum, and questions should be specific to a single issue, and not grow like a forum-thread or conversation.